# NullPointerException in TvInputManager.getTvInputList()

Tags: android, android-tv

In my Android TV app I'm trying to get a list of TV inputs with the following code:

```
TvInputManager tvInputManager = (TvInputManager) getSystemService(Context.TV_INPUT_SERVICE);
List<TvInputInfo> tvInputInfos = tvInputManager.getTvInputList();
```

but a `NullPointerException` is raised inside `getTvInputList()`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.List android.media.tv.ITvInputManager.getTvInputList(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.media.tv.TvInputManager.getTvInputList(TvInputManager.java:943)
```

Looking at the source code of `TvInputManager` it seems that `mService` is null:

```
return mService.getTvInputList(mUserId);
```

How is `getTvInputList()` supposed to be used then ?

Comment: Any explanation for the downvotes?

Comment: I guess some people see `NullPointerException` and blindly hit downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're running this code on an android device which is not a true "Android TV" device. I mean a lot of TV box running android exist, but few of them are truly "Android TV" devices.
You can check it using following code:

```
boolean trueAndroidTV = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK);
```

Finally you can test if your device really supports TV Input Framework using following code:

```
boolean tifSupport = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LIVE_TV);
```

Comment: what's your device ?

Comment: It's a Wetek Play 2

Comment: Well it's not a certified "Android TV" device, I guess you don't have play store on that box. I am very surprised it declares the "android.software.leanback" feature. Here is a pretty exhaustive "Android TV" device list: http://bytel.tv/androidtv_devices.html

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still surprised that a NPE is thrown inside a SDK method, even if it's running on a non-TV Android device.

Comment: Yes it would be cleaner to return a null TvInputManager instead. Finally you can test if your device really supports TV Input Framework using following code:

Answer (score 1):

You need create or download a tv input application on the same device. To create a tv input app, you should look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/tvinput.html) document.

Or you can download [Pluto Tv](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/pluto-inc/pluto-tv-android-tv/pluto-tv-android-tv-2-2-6-release/pluto-tv-2-2-6-leanback-android-apk-download/) application from Play Store

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same null pointer exception, and fixed it by creating `tv_core_hardware.xml` in the system/etc/permissions

Save the following XML content to this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<permissions>
    <!-- These are the hardware components that all television devices must
         include.  Devices with optional hardware must also include extra hardware
         files.
    -->
    <feature name="android.hardware.audio.output" />
    <feature name="android.hardware.location" />
    <feature name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <feature name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
    <feature name="android.hardware.type.television" />
    <feature name="android.software.app_widgets" />
    <feature name="android.software.backup" />
    <feature name="android.software.leanback" />
    <feature name="android.software.leanback_only" />
    <feature name="android.software.live_tv" />
    <feature name="android.software.print" />
    <feature name="android.software.voice_recognizers" />
</permissions>
```

Or alternatively download the it from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/atv/+/refs/tags/android-cts-5.1_r20/tv_core_hardware.xml), and place this in system/etc/permissions folder and reboot the TV.

This will enable both `PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK` and `PackageManager.FEATURE_LIVE_TV` system features.

Note: This only works if you have root permission.